# How do I get my menu to work in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, menu

I have a CSS menu that works great in Chrome, it is absolutely miserable in Firefox. I've tried different positioning, etc. at least 50 different ways with no fix. Check it out in FF here: http://morrisonhosting.com/ryan/BusinessSite/index.html

Comment: i got it the problem is in your `css`

Answer (score 2):

take a look of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/u65SB/)
just copy and paste code from it and your menu is work in every browser infact ie7 supportable 
check this out :-)
here is html code :-)

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="subnavi">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FaQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul class="subnavi">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is css modify it according to your needs

```
#nav{list-style:none; background:#333; height:30px; line-height:30px;}
ul#nav > li{ 
    float:left; 
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
    position:relative;
}
ul#nav li a{
    padding:0 15px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
#nav li a:hover{
    background:#ccc;
}
ul.subnavi{
    list-style:none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    display:none;
}
ul.subnavi li{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    float:none;
}
ul#nav li ul.subnavi li a{
    color:#333;
}
ul#nav li ul.subnavi li a:hover {
    background:#333;
    color:#fff;
}
#nav li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Holy crap! I posted this an totally forgot about it. Thank you so much for the response!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you rebuild your code using a clean example, such as in:

http://www.handy-html.com/create-a-simple-css-dropdown-menu/

As of now, your code breaks even in Chrome (moving from 2nd to 3rd option in main menu), so a major haul seems to be a good option.

The above code worked well in all browsers I tested (Safari, Chrome, FF)

Best wishes,